# Incompatible types in assigmnet of int to char[16] error - Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I've created an array of structs but I'm getting the error written on the title of this question. I'm still new to this so I was wondering if I could get some help.

Code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  i = 0;
}
```

```
#define LIMIT 27

struct protocol {
  char create[16];
  char character;
  int values;
  int minimum;
  int maximum;
};

struct protocol channels[LIMIT];
int i;

void create_channels() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    Serial.print("Enter the channel description");
    channels[i].create = Serial.read();
    Serial.print("Enter the starting character: ");
    channels[i].character = Serial.read();

    if (i == LIMIT) {
      for (i = 0; i < LIMIT; i++)
      {
        Serial.println(channels[i].create);
        Serial.println(channels[i].character);
      }
      i = 0;

    }
  }
}
```

Error:

```
cw.ino:24:38: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'int' to 'char [16]'
     channels[i].create = Serial.read();
```

Comment: You can't copy data to a whole character array using the `=` operator. I don't know the details of the Arduino interfaces, but probably you need to use `strcpy`. But not even that: why are you trying to put an `int` into a `char[]` array?

Comment: @AdrianMole I'll look into that as well. Thanks for the response

Comment: @AdrianMole I actually think it's the "Serial.available() > 0"  interfering with that bit but I'm not 100% sure. The monitor is meant to read the string and then add it into the array

Comment: Serial.read() returns an integer? Please look at your docs to see how it's meant to be used.

Comment: looks like [`Serial.read()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/serial/read) returns one int at a time. You'll probably need to setup a loop to store each value read at `.create[0]`, `.create[1]`, etc, unless there's an arduino function that does that for you. But you should check that it _doesn't_ return -1 before assigning in `.create`.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/

Comment: @Benzene yes, error log is OK now.

Comment: @hyde Just looked into it, thanks for the info :)

Comment: @yano Just looked into it, thanks for the info :)

Comment: @Juraj Didn't know this website existed, thanks for that